# Text to column task in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
;
;
ACHTUNG;Dies ist das Ergebnis einer Testversion. Alle Ergebnisse ohne Gewaehr.
;Bei Rueckfragen oder Unstimmigkeiten wenden Sie sich an aron.proebsting@mwtest.de;
;
;
;
PSD4_Status;|;
PSD5_Status;|;
mux;<-;PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;
PSD6_Status;|;
cycle_state;<-;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;PSD4_Status;
PsdEhr_out;<-;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
Entfernung_Abzweigung;<-;Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime;Aktuelle_Pos.id;Aktuelle_Pos.lane;Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError;Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique;Aktuelle_Pos.length;Child_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Child_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Child_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Child_Segment.attributes.lanes;Child_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Child_Segment.attributes.ramp;Child_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Child_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Child_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Child_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Child_Segment.attributeIndex;Child_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Child_Segment.id;Child_Segment.parentId;Child_Segment.identity;Child_Segment.completeFlags;Child_Segment.childSegments[0];Child_Segment.childSegments[1];Child_Segment.childSegments[2];Child_Segment.childSegments[3];Child_Segment.childSegments[4];Get_Child_It.indexStart;Get_Child_It.indexCurrent;Get_Child_It.id;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.lanes;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.ramp;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Aktuelles_Segment.attributeIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.id;Aktuelles_Segment.parentId;Aktuelles_Segment.identity;Aktuelles_Segment.completeFlags;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[1];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[2];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[3];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[4];Child_from_Parent.geometry.curvatureStart;Child_from_Parent.geometry.curvatureEnd;Child_from_Parent.geometry.length;Child_from_Parent.geometry.branchAngle;Child_from_Parent.attributes.lanes;Child_from_Parent.attributes.ramp;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isStraightestPath;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isADASQuality;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Child_from_Parent.attributeIndex;Child_from_Parent.speedLimitIndex;Child_from_Parent.id;Child_from_Parent.parentId;Child_from_Parent.identity;Child_from_Parent.completeFlags;Child_from_Parent.childSegments[0];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[1];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[2];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[3];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[4];Min_Strassenklasse;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0];Child_Segment.geometry.length;Child_from_Parent.attributes.streetClass;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
Steigung_gueltig;<-;Aktuelle_Pos.length;Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime;Aktuelle_Pos.lane;Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError;Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.lanes;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.ramp;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Aktuelles_Segment.attributeIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.id;Aktuelles_Segment.parentId;Aktuelles_Segment.identity;Aktuelles_Segment.completeFlags;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[1];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[2];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[3];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[4];Aktuelle_Pos.id;Suchweite;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite.distance;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite.attribute.nextAttribute;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite.attribute.offset;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite.attribute.type;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite.segmentId;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.searchDistance;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.currentIndex;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.currentDistance;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.searchType;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.searchDirection;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.currentId;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite_It.currentOffset;Steigung_innerhalb_Suchweite.attribute.value;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
Kruemmung_gueltig;<-;Aktuelle_Pos.length;Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime;Aktuelle_Pos.lane;Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError;Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.lanes;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.ramp;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Aktuelles_Segment.attributeIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.id;Aktuelles_Segment.parentId;Aktuelles_Segment.identity;Aktuelles_Segment.completeFlags;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[1];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[2];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[3];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[4];Aktuelle_Pos.id;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
BuiltUpArea;<-;Aktuelle_Pos.length;Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime;Aktuelle_Pos.lane;Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError;Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.lanes;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.ramp;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Aktuelles_Segment.attributeIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.id;Aktuelles_Segment.parentId;Aktuelles_Segment.identity;Aktuelles_Segment.completeFlags;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[1];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[2];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[3];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[4];Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Aktuelle_Pos.id;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
ADASQuality;<-;Aktuelle_Pos.length;Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime;Aktuelle_Pos.lane;Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError;Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.lanes;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.ramp;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Aktuelles_Segment.attributeIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.id;Aktuelles_Segment.parentId;Aktuelles_Segment.identity;Aktuelles_Segment.completeFlags;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[1];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[2];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[3];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[4];Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Aktuelle_Pos.id;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
NumberOfChilds;<-;Aktuelle_Pos.length;Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime;Aktuelle_Pos.lane;Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError;Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length;Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.lanes;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.ramp;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Aktuelles_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Aktuelles_Segment.attributeIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Aktuelles_Segment.id;Aktuelles_Segment.parentId;Aktuelles_Segment.identity;Aktuelles_Segment.completeFlags;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[1];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[2];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[3];Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[4];Child_from_Parent.geometry.curvatureStart;Child_from_Parent.geometry.curvatureEnd;Child_from_Parent.geometry.length;Child_from_Parent.geometry.branchAngle;Child_from_Parent.attributes.lanes;Child_from_Parent.attributes.ramp;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isStraightestPath;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isADASQuality;Child_from_Parent.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Child_from_Parent.attributeIndex;Child_from_Parent.speedLimitIndex;Child_from_Parent.id;Child_from_Parent.parentId;Child_from_Parent.identity;Child_from_Parent.completeFlags;Child_from_Parent.childSegments[0];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[1];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[2];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[3];Child_from_Parent.childSegments[4];Min_Strassenklasse;Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0];Child_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart;Child_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd;Child_Segment.geometry.length;Child_Segment.geometry.branchAngle;Child_Segment.attributes.lanes;Child_Segment.attributes.streetClass;Child_Segment.attributes.ramp;Child_Segment.attributes.isMostProbablePath;Child_Segment.attributes.isStraightestPath;Child_Segment.attributes.isADASQuality;Child_Segment.attributes.isBuiltUpArea;Child_Segment.attributeIndex;Child_Segment.speedLimitIndex;Child_Segment.parentId;Child_Segment.identity;Child_Segment.completeFlags;Child_Segment.childSegments[0];Child_Segment.childSegments[1];Child_Segment.childSegments[2];Child_Segment.childSegments[3];Child_Segment.childSegments[4];Get_Child_It.indexStart;Get_Child_It.indexCurrent;Get_Child_It.id;Child_Segment.id;Child_from_Parent.attributes.streetClass;Aktuelle_Pos.id;PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle();PSD6_CAN;PSD6_Status;PSD5_Status;cycle_state;PSD4_Status;
```

This is how my csv file currently looks. I want to create the file like we do in excel text to column with ; seperator. I cannot do it in excel as I want to automize this process because there are many files like this. I am new to python so not sure how to proceed ahead. Some suggestion would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to keep every row in your csv file? This will be a slight problem because you do not have enough delimiters per row to account for each column. This code will open your file, check how many delimiters each row needs, add the appropriate number of delimiters, save the new csv file with those delimiters, then open the new csv file using Pandas csv_read:

```py
import pandas as pd

path = "Text.csv"
text = [f for f in open(path)]

# Find the maximum number of delimiters (;) in any given row
numDelims = []
for line in text:
    count = line.count(';')
    numDelims.append(count)
maxDelims = np.max(numDelims)

# Add the missing number of delimiters to each row to account for the columns
for x in range(len(text)):
    text[x] = text[x].replace("\n", ";"*(maxDelims-numDelims[x])+"\n")
    
# Save the new csv file with all the additional delimters
newFile = "Save.csv"
# Save to a new text file
with open(newFile, "w+") as file:
    file.writelines(text)
    
# Read the file back in as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("Save.csv", sep=";")
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read your file using pandas ([pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)), such as:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('pathofyourfile', sep=';')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read_csv` with the `sep` and `skiprows` parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';', skiprows=13)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Entfernung_Abzweigung  <- Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime  \
0      Steigung_gueltig  <-      Aktuelle_Pos.length   
1     Kruemmung_gueltig  <-      Aktuelle_Pos.length   
2           BuiltUpArea  <-      Aktuelle_Pos.length   
3           ADASQuality  <-      Aktuelle_Pos.length   
4        NumberOfChilds  <-      Aktuelle_Pos.length   

            Aktuelle_Pos.id  Aktuelle_Pos.lane  \
0  Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime  Aktuelle_Pos.lane   
1  Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime  Aktuelle_Pos.lane   
2  Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime  Aktuelle_Pos.lane   
3  Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime  Aktuelle_Pos.lane   
4  Aktuelle_Pos.inhibitTime  Aktuelle_Pos.lane   

   Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError  Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique  \
0  Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError  Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique   
1  Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError  Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique   
2  Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError  Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique   
3  Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError  Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique   
4  Aktuelle_Pos.longitudinalError  Aktuelle_Pos.isLocationUnique   

                         Aktuelle_Pos.length  \
0  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart   
1  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart   
2  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart   
3  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart   
4  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart   

     Child_Segment.geometry.curvatureStart  \
0  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd   
1  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd   
2  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd   
3  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd   
4  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd   

      Child_Segment.geometry.curvatureEnd  ...  \
0  Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.branchAngle  ...   
1       Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length  ...   
2       Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length  ...   
3       Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length  ...   
4       Aktuelles_Segment.geometry.length  ...   

  Aktuelles_Segment.childSegments[0]  \
0                                NaN   
1                                NaN   
2                                NaN   
3                                NaN   
4                   Child_Segment.id   

              Child_Segment.geometry.length  \
0                                       NaN   
1                                       NaN   
2                                       NaN   
3                                       NaN   
4  Child_from_Parent.attributes.streetClass   

  Child_from_Parent.attributes.streetClass  PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle()  \
0                                      NaN                           NaN   
1                                      NaN                           NaN   
2                                      NaN                           NaN   
3                                      NaN                           NaN   
4                          Aktuelle_Pos.id  PsdEhr_ProcessMessageCycle()   

   PSD6_CAN  PSD6_Status  PSD5_Status  cycle_state  PSD4_Status Unnamed: 84  
0       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN  
1       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN  
2       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN  
3       NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN         NaN  
4  PSD6_CAN  PSD6_Status  PSD5_Status  cycle_state  PSD4_Status         NaN
```